# Non-entity class extending an entity class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a party class that's mapped to a table and is annotated with @entity like so:

```
@entity
@Table(name = "PARTY")
public class party{

    @Id
    protected long partyId;
}
```

I also have a class representing an address:

```
@entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class address{

    @Id
    protected long partyId;
}
```

The party Id can be used as a foreign key to get an address from the address table.

Sometimes I want to return a party by itself and sometimes I want to return a party with an address. I thought I could just make a separate class that extends party but adds in the address like so:

```
public class partyWithAddress extends party{

    @OneToMany
    private List<Address> addresses;
}
```

But I get an error:

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: partyWithAddress

I read about entity inheritance but I still am pretty lost. Can anyone help?

Comment: why create another class? just create another method for this task.

Comment: @ShadabFaiz what do you mean create another method? On the model?

Answer (score 2):

If your class is not entity then it wont be recognized by JPA, you need to annotate it with @Entity first , then comes which inheritance policy you would like to use , by default the singltable inheritance is used which means all children and their parent is in one table and this is recommended in case you do not have much difference between your entities, for further information about inheritance check this [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/inheritance.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly suggest avoiding inheritance hereand just add

```
@OneToMany 
List<Address> addresses;
```

to the `Party` entity, and handling in your code the case for that list of `Addresses` being empty/null.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using the pojos as models to be returned by a controller for certain routes. Some routes I don't want to return an address even if there is one.

Comment: Then you'd need to have two separate entity classes mapped to the same database table, if your `PartyWithAddress` class is not an entity then JPA will not resolve its `@OneToMany` relationship with addresses. This only occurs on Entities.

For a given database row, do you want to be able to return it both as a `Party` and as a `PartyWithAddress` or do you only want to treat a given row as one type or the other?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Just one type or the other. Basically I'm trying to return a json with party info with a nested address but sometimes i want to return a json with party and no nested address

Comment: I would consider having a single `@Entity` that contains the `@OneToMany` mapping. I'd then have two Data Transfer Object (`DTO`) classes  - these could use an inheritance hierarchy - and i'd convert from the single `Entity` class, into the appropriate DTO based on how I wished to return the data. This provides separation of concern between the mapping to the database table and the various ways you may wish to view the same data record. Alternately instead of DTO consider using configurable serialization such as Jackson's `@JsonView`. Either way I'd solve at view time, not at retrieval time.